# Good physical example of a (contravariant) vector field?

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

I am teaching some problem classes for a first course on general relativity and would like to be able to give examples of contravariant and covariant vectors, as an introduction to the theory of tensors.

A standard example for a high school student of a vector field might be the velocity of a particle or of a river or of the wind or something. The problem being that, arising as derivatives, these are all manifestly covariant objects, which we would now like to convey to students as being actually dual to a "true" vector field.

Does anyone have either a good example of a naturally arising, contravariant object or of a good way to illustrate to students the concept of a contravariant object and the distinction with covariant objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't agree on the covariant character of the velocity field. The velocity field is of the same kind of the displacement field, i.e. it is (naturally) a *contravariant* vector (the *temporal* derivative doesn't matter).
A natural first example of covariant vector is the "area covector". Usually it is confused (or simply associated) with a vector: in three dimensions it is equal to the cross product of the (vector) sides of the associated parallelogram. The area is a covariant vector: when it acts on a vector (e.g. a velocity) it gives a scalar (e.g. the flux of a physical quantity). In the same way, when the area covector acts on a displacement vector, it gives the volume scalar (the volume of the parallelepiped defined by the surface and the displacement vector)

Comment: I would say that the derivative of any scalar valued function $f$ is covariant as it changes covariantly with respect to change of coordinates, by the chain rule
$$ \partial_i f (x^1,\ldots,x^n) = \frac{\partial x^j}{\partial \tilde{x}^i} \partial_j f(\tilde{x}^1, \ldots, \tilde{x}^n) $$

I would think of the area "vector" in 3 dimensions not as a vector but as a rank (0,2)-tensor, as it eats two vector fields to return a scalar function. It should be a skew-symmetric 2-form which integrates over surfaces to give the area.

Comment: 1) I agree with the fact that the derivative of a scalar function with respect to the coordinate variables is a covector. What I criticized was your statement that the velocity field is a covariant field. 2) As for the "area covector" I think we are considering different obects. You mention an area 2-form, which assigns to a parallelogram a signed scalar. With my example I was referring to the area as oriented "vector" (better: covector), which contracted with another vector gives a signed scalar (volume). So my area covector is the Hodge dual of the area 2-form

Comment: I see :) so how do you define the velocity vector field? For me the velocity is naturally a derivative. Is there a physically motivated rationale for converting this into a contravariant object?

Comment: In the context of continuum mechanics the velocity field is the partial time derivative of the placement field $\phi(X,t)$. This is a map $\phi: B\times [0,T]\to \mathbf R^3$, where $B$ is the material configuration. So, in this context, $\phi$ is vector valued. If $\phi(X,t)$ is a vector, also $\partial \phi(X,t)/\partial t$ is a vector. However also in a relativistic context velocity is a 4-vector $V^\mu$ , not covector. Infact it is the derivative of the position four-vector $X^\mu$ with respect to an invariant (proper time), NOT with respect to  the time-coordinate.

Comment: Ok I now see what you were saying. Thanks for clearing that up for me, good answer :)